# predicted values for glmer AICcmodavg

Tags: r, glm, predict

I know that one can get the predicted values (in original scale ~ probability) and their SE for the fixed effects with AICcmodavg, but I'm trying without any success... Can someone help me with that? Thanks in advance

```
library(lme4)
(gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
              data = cbpp, family = binomial))
fixef(gm1)

library("AICcmodavg")

predictSE(gm1, 
          newdata=as.data.frame(period=c("period1","period2","period3","period4")), 
          type="response", 
          se.fit=TRUE, 
          level=0, 
          print.matrix=F)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to read `levels(cbpp$period)`, and not `as.data.frame()` but `data.frame()`

```
levels(cbpp$period)
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4"

predictSE(gm1, 
          newdata = data.frame(period=c("1", "2", "3", "4")),
          type = "response", 
          se.fit = TRUE, 
          level = 0, 
          print.matrix = F)
```

**[Edited]**

a simple method of searching a cause of error

```
fit <- ...(..., data = df)

predictSE(fit, newdata = df)
predictSE(fit, newdata = ...)

# If 1st predictSE() doesn't run, it means the model causes error.
# If 1st runs but 2nd doesn't, it means it is due to newdata.
```

If your model has two factor;

```
newd <- expand.grid(name1 = levels(df$name1), name2 = levels(df$name2))
predictSE(fit, newdata = newd)
 # pred <- predictSE(fit, newdata = newd)
 # cbind(newd, pred)            # help to interpret
```

Comment: perfect! thank you for the quick reply. can you please tell me how to write the line for 'newdata' if my model has two factors.

Comment: sorry to abuse of your knoledgment @cuttlefish44 I am doing that and I get an error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'inter1' not found` when I do what you said with this data and fit: `df= gsheet2tbl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GotdpK0x036O4Reus9c-C6lqeiQkc35rx1z7N0Dx6PQ/edit?usp=sharing") ; fit<- glmer(cbind(diseased,n-diseased)~ var:trt + 
(1|blk/var/trt), family="binomial",data=df); newd <- expand.grid(var = levels(df[,"var"]), 
                    trt = levels(df[,"trt"])); 
predictSE(fit, newdata = newd)
` Do you figure out what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: @Juanchi; I can't make `fit` without message and `predictSE(fit, newdata=df)` doesn't run, it means you failed to make a proper model to give `predictSE()`. For example, `fit3<- glmer(cbind(diseased,n - diseased) ~ var*trt + (1|blk), family="binomial",data=df); predictSE(fit, newdata = newd)` runs.

Comment: Great! yes, I have this message `fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient` and what I found about it is that the dataset is a bit small.. thank you!

Comment: Brillant... it's fitting without error now. Thank you very much for your time!